# Google Earth - Difference between versions?

Tags: software-installation

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

When I do:

```
apt-cache search google-earth
```

apt gives me three packages:

```
google-earth-ec-stable [Version: 7.3.2.5776-r0]
google-earth-pro-stable [Version: 7.3.2.5776-r0]
google-earth-stable [Version:  7.1.8.3036-r0
```

I already have google-earth-stable installed on my machine. I wanted to install version 7.3. Which one should I choose? "ec" or "pro"? What is the difference between these two?

Comment: FYI: I'd suggest checking what Ubuntu you are actually running, a fully-upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system will report 16.04.6 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/), so either you haven't fully upgraded since before 2018-March-3 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/03/03/ubuntu-16-04-4-lts-released/) and really need to, or you're running a later version.   *It could be you provided your install release, and not what you're actually running*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC stands for `Enterprise Client`
Pro obviously for `Professional`

They just add some features you can use with Google Earth. The standard version is all about Looking around, the Pro Version adds Features like `Measuring Areas instead of straight lines only`, the pictures also have a higher resolution. GE EC is something in between